# Shell Scripting: Fuse all duplcate lines inside a file into 1

Tags: linux, bash, shell, text-processing

Here is the sample file with the duplicate lines:

```
abs
bsa
bsc
abs
bsa
bsb
```

Here is what the output should be (no duplicates):

```
abs
bsa
bsc
bsb
```

I tried out the uniq `-u` command, but it deletes out the duplicate lines, so would it be better to use `sed` or `awk`? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a programming language which offers associative arrays (a.k.a. hashes) or sets. Store each line into the set/hash, when you encounter it the first time. You output the line only if it has not been in your array before. You **can** do it in *bash* (search the man-page for associative arrays) or *awk* (where **every** array is associative), or in nearly any other language (*zsh*, *Ruby*, *Perl*, ....). A problem could be if the input is so huge that you run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: `'uniq'` does not detect repeated lines unless they are
>   adjacent.  You  may  want  to  sort  the  input
>          first, or use `'sort -u'` without `'uniq'`.

```
sort -u yourfile
```

The output:

```
abs
bsa
bsb
bsc
```